# FFMPEG audio sample data

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sample

I'm beginner to FFMPEG API and I need to process audio sample. 
I see that audio sample data stored in AVFrame->data[0], but I don't know how audio sample stored in FFMPEG AVFrame.

For example:
There are 2 channels,

```
frame->nb_samples = 64, 
frame->linesize[0] = 256.
```

I don't know how audio sample data stored in frame->data[0].
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio samples are pointed to by

```
frame->data[0]
frame->data[1]
```

and they're `frame->linesize[0]` bytes long

The `sample_fmt` of your `AVCodecContext` will tell you the format of the samples, which will be one of the following:

```
AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP
AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT
AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P
AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16
```

For `FLT` you cast the pointers to `float*` and for `S16` you cast to `int16_t*`